# Lualatex : opacity not working in pstricks

Tags: luatex, pstricks, transparency

The opacity doesn't work with LuaLaTeX (I'm on Windows, I use TexMaker with the MikTex distribution, packages are all in the latest versions) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85, pstricks, pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}  \psset{unit=1cm}
        \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,4) %\grille
            \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,0)(10,4)
            \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.4,linecolor=red](2,1)(8,3)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I see that :

[image]

instead of :

[image]

What's the problem???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the log file tells you the reason:

```
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is not loaded.
```

In a current LaTeX you can load the pdfmanagement with `\DocumentMetadata`:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}  \psset{unit=1cm}
        \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,4) %\grille
            \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,0)(10,4)
            \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.4,linecolor=red](2,1)(8,3)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did aso  long research without result...