pst-plot transparency, wedge line and anchor
I am trying to reproduce the following plot (ignoring the grey background):

For that, I want to use the pst-plot package inside a document I build with LuaLaTeX (this is important). I am close, but there are still a couple of things that I just cannot make work.
This is my code:
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue2}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen2}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myred2}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow2}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{textcolor}{HTML}{666666}

% Fonts
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

%RADAR PLOT
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-6.25)(4,4)
        \psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,360)
        \psaxes[labels=none](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
        \psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myblue2]{3.75}{0}{90}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myyellow2]{3.95}{90}{180}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myred2]{1.75}{180}{270}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=mygreen2]{3.15}{270}{360}
        %legend
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myblue2](1.25,-4.75){1}{150}{210} \rput(1.75,-4.75){English}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myyellow2](-2.75,-4.75){1}{150}{210} \rput(-2.25,-4.75){Español}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=myred2](-2.75,-6){1}{150}{210} \rput(-2.25,-6){CH}
        \pswedge[fillcolor=mygreen2](1.25,-6){1}{150}{210} \rput(1.75,-6){Italiano}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}

Which produces:

Note that I want to keep the dashed polar sub-axes as well. It is close to the original plot, but there are a few things I cannot accomplish:

I need the wedges to be transparent; the opacity argument does not
seem to work, or I am not placing it in the right place.
I want the wedges without outline; I do not know how to remove those
lines.
Less important, but I would like to have the legend labels
left-aligned; is there a way to specify a west anchor for the wedges
and labels in the legend?


Add \DocumentMetadata{}  before \documentclass. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689889/47927

\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\definecolor{myblue2}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen2}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myred2}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow2}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{textcolor}{HTML}{666666}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-6.25)(4,4)
        \psaxes[labels=none](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
        \psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,360)
        \psset{opacity=0.5}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myblue2]{3.75}{0}{90}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myyellow2]{3.95}{90}{180}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myred2]{1.75}{180}{270}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=mygreen2]{3.15}{270}{360}
        %legend
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myblue2](1.25,-4.75){1}{150}{210} \rput(1.75,-4.75){English}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myyellow2](-2.75,-4.75){1}{150}{210} \rput(-2.25,-4.75){Español}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=myred2](-2.75,-6){1}{150}{210} \rput(-2.25,-6){CH}
        \pswedge*[linecolor=mygreen2](1.25,-6){1}{150}{210} \rput(1.75,-6){Italiano}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}



what does the * after \pswedge do? fill in the same linecolor?

it uses the linecolor for filling
